# query to fetch the oracle CPU usage for last 1 hour

Tags: oracle, cpu-usage, percentage

How to query oracle CPU usage for last 1 hour as percentage (every 1 min)?

Comment: What's your motivation?  Let's say it comes to 70%  What does that mean? You can give back 30% of your CPU's? It might mean that ... it might not.  If you are looking for a useful metric in terms of server utilization from an Oracle perspective, perhaps check out Average Active Sessions.  More info here https://www.slideshare.net/jberesni/aas-oaktable-world-2013-jb

Comment: I would like to see the trend of the CPU being utilized by oracle for the last one hour.where exactly the CPU is getting most utilized over the last one hour.i am looking as a percentage.I

Answer (score 4):

You may try to use the following statement giving `username`, `sid`, `client` and `module` information statistics for last one hour-period if you have access for `gv$sesstat`,`gv$session` and `gv$statname` dynamic performance views. You may replace `gv$` with `v$` if your system is not `RAC`(`Real Application Cluster`) :

```
select * from
(
select username,sid,
       round((cpu_usage/(
                        select sum(value) total_cpu_usage
                          from gv$sesstat t
                         inner join gv$session  s on ( t.sid = s.sid )
                         inner join gv$statname n on ( t.statistic# = n.statistic# )
                         where n.name like '%CPU used by this session%'
                           and nvl(s.sql_exec_start, s.prev_exec_start) >= sysdate-1/24
                        ))*100,2) cpu_usage_per_cent,
       module_info,client_info 
  from
(
select nvl(s.username,'Oracle Internal Proc.') username,s.sid,t.value cpu_usage, nvl(s.module, s.program) module_info, decode(s.osuser,'oracle', s.client_info, s.osuser) client_info
  from gv$sesstat t
       inner join gv$session  s on ( t.sid = s.sid )
       inner join gv$statname n on ( t.statistic# = n.statistic# )
 where n.name like '%CPU used by this session%'
   and nvl(s.sql_exec_start, s.prev_exec_start) >= sysdate-1/24
) s1
)
order by cpu_usage_per_cent desc;
```

Comment: Hi Ozhan ,thanks for the query ,i was looking for the utilization irrespective of the sql, i.e i should group by based on the each minute and i think i can use trunc(sysdate,'mi') in the select and also group it to get the cpu usage.will that work

Answer (score 1):

As this information is available in the EM it means it's available in the database. Check something like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140188/oracle-em-11g-query-to-find-out-cpu-utilization

Comment: hi,i checked the query but how do i convert into a percentage similar to the SAR -u which we use to get from the unix

Answer (score 1):

Is a large or small X a good thing or a bad thing? You can substitute any unit of measure and find a flaw in making a value judgement based upon the interpretation of such measurements.

My argument is that you cannot know the answer to those types of questions apart from the overall experience of the users using the system.

To prove my point, consider Oracle's CEO on stage, years ago, touting the then new Oracle Parallel Query option. While he's running the query in parallel, he's going to be sorely disappointed if all of the machine's resources aren't nearly 100% busy. But before and after his query is complete he wants that machine to be 100% idle.

The *only* way to tell which state is good is to know your users.

To determine health you should "talk" (and talk) to the users about their experiences. A good way to do that is to measure their experiences automatically using some sort of service level agreement infrastructure while occasionally tracing experiences so that you can keep track of performance with respect to change (all kinds of change) and more easily diagnose performance problems.